# Нормально ли задавать 2 внешних ключа для 1 таблицы? SQL

Tags: sql, foreign-key, нормализация-данных

Допустим простую систему, где есть задание, заказчик, исполнитель.
Соответственно есть таблицы **Tasks** и **Users**.
Нормально ли будет добавить 2 внешних ключа в **Tasks** (*CustomerID*, *PerformerID*) для одного поля таблицы **Users** (*ID*). Нормальная ли это практика и не нарушает ли это правила нормализации?

Comment: Может быть и больше, в зависимости от.... зависимостей 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, нормально, так как пользователь может быть как заказчиком, так и исполнителем